# Is there a way to access/modify files on a Linux machine from an ASP.NET (.NET Core) Application?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, asp.net-core, filesystems

I am still a newbie in .NET and need to find out if there is a way to access/modify files on a Linux machine from an .NET/.NET Core application.

As far as I managed to find now, an option should be to connect via SSH to the Linux machine and make the operations. Is this a viable solution? Are there any out-of-the-box .NET Libraries that address this? I would really appreciate any suggestions/example/experiences.

For example, need to be able to make operations like: chmod, chown and other custom operations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you mean access/modify a _remote_ file system?

Comment: @Fildor Yes the existing ASP.NET app should be able to access a Linux-based remote file system and make changes.